# See the readable names with jemalloc

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jvm, jemalloc

We are trying to catch a memory leak, and we are using with jemalloc. How do you change the tree to display symbol/class names? Right now, our gif looks like this:
[image]

On most tutorials I see, they just say to set the following 2 env vars:

```
 echo $LD_PRELOAD
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so
```

```
 echo $MALLOC_CONF
prof:true,lg_prof_interval:29,lg_prof_sample:17
```

The command I'm running is: jeprof --show_bytes --gif `which java` jeprof*.heap > mem.gif

We are running a java application from a docker-compose file, using the image: openjdk:13-jdk-alpine

Comment: you should check async-profiler, I bet it does a lot more for you

Comment: I will check it out if jemalloc cannot give me information I need

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: I'm running a java application...?

Comment: Tracking memory leaks in a Java application doesn't involve looking at the usage of jemalloc, unless you're debugging the JVM itself, in which case you need advice that you're not likely to find on SO. When you're asking for class names, do you mean Java class names? If so, you need use a Java memory profiler, not a jemalloc tool.

Comment: Yes, im trying to see if there is a leak in native memory. I dont literally mean class names, i mean such as the image at the bottom of this article. https://technology.blog.gov.uk/2015/12/11/using-jemalloc-to-get-to-the-bottom-of-a-memory-leak/. it provides readable content, not memory addresses